# Error: The character encoding was not declared

Tags: html, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, w3c-validation

I use minify for both css and js via the W3 Total Cache plugin.

In W3C validator I get:

*Error: The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252.

Error: Changing character encoding utf-8 and reparsing.

Fatal Error: Changing encoding at this point would need non-streamable behavior.*

This is what I have in the source code:

And my head.php looks like this

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.travelersuniverse.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/79a08/single.include.e8a63c.css" media="all" />

<script async type="text/javascript" src="http://www.travelersuniverse.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/79a08/default.include.b31316.js"></script>
</head>
```

For some reason, the W3 Total Cache inserts the minified files above the character encoding. 
How do I place them after the character encoding is set?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you not declared a `doctype`?

Comment: Yes, the doctype is declared.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but I had the same problem today and I was searching around for the answer till I found it myself. So if it can help someone...

I had the following errors when trying to validate my [JSHangman.html](http://ibbtek.altervista.org/js/jshangman.html) page on the [w3c html validator](https://validator.w3.org):

> ```
> Error: The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using windows-1252.
>
> Error: A charset attribute on a meta element found after the first 1024 bytes.
>
> At line 39, column 25
>
>  charset="utf-8" />↩  </head>↩
>
> Error: Changing character encoding utf-8 and reparsing.
>
> From line 39, column 5; to line 39, column 28
>
> itle>↩    <meta charset="utf-8" />↩  </h
>
> Fatal Error: Changing encoding at this point would need non-streamable behavior.
>
> At line 39, column 28
>
> arset="utf-8" />↩  </head>↩  <
> ```

In fact, the answer was in the second error line:

> Error: A charset attribute on a meta element found after the first 1024 bytes.

I had a big comment (something like 20 lines) between my <!DOCTYPE> tag and my <\html> tag and that was the issue. My problem was solved as soon as I deleted it.